# Advanced SAT algebra practice

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm helping some friends prepare for the SAT and I'm reviewing some SAT algebra practice. Can someone double check if my answer for these two questions are correct?

> 1. Which of the following is equal to $\frac{a+b}{b}$?
>
> A) $1+\frac ba$
>
> B) $1+\frac ab$
>
> C) $\frac ab+ \frac ba$
>
> D) $\frac{b-a}{b}$
>
> E) $\frac{a-b}{a}$

So to solve this I did the following:

$\frac{a+b}{b} = \frac ab+ \frac bb= \frac ab+1$

> 2. If $ab=a-c$, which of the following is equal to b?
>
> A) $1-\frac ca$
>
> B) $1+\frac ca$
>
> C) $1+\frac ac$
>
> D) $1-\frac ac$
>
> E) $\frac{a+c}{a}$

$b=\frac{a-c}{a} = \frac aa - \frac ca = 1-\frac ca$

Comment: both are correct.

Comment: This reminds me of how poorly tests like the SAT measured my ability in mathematics.

Comment: All these questions just rely on algebra rules it seems like... as I'm going through them I realize I'm unsure of some myself lol

Comment: You reasoning is correct (um, you chose B) for 1?  cause a/b + 1 = 1 + 1/b? right?)  But I'm going to quibble... with the test... *not* with you.... that question 2 is incorrect.  If $a  = 0$ then none of the answers are correct and the value of b is indeterminable.  But that's the test's mistake.  Not yours.... (also if $a = 0$ then $c$ also is equal to $0$).